# How can I get list of foreign server's tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I create a [foreign server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) in postgresql. Before adding foreign table, I want to get list of tables in this foreign server.

Is there any way I can do this?

This sql query show the created foreign tables:

```
select * from information_schema.foreign_tables
```

But I want to know table names and structure before create it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. You have to connect to the remote data source directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dblink to do that.  It is pretty unpleasant as you have to list all the column names and types.

You can put the name of the foreign server as the first argument to dblink:

```
create extension dblink;
select * from dblink('the_foreign_server','select * from pg_tables') foo(sc name, tb name, ow name, ts name, ind bool, rul bool, tr bool, rls bool);
```